# Prerequisites for creating c# app for Oracle Administration

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, oracle, oracle.manageddataaccess

I am trying to create a c# application to administer oracle databases using a web interface. I have been using Oracle.ManagedDataAcccess.dll for usual database operations (CRUD) however I have not been able to find any information on whether there exists features to help carry out say, data file, control file or redo logs specific manipulation or may be connect to RMAN and execute commands from within the web based app.

Comment: Yes, you can execute any command with Oracle.ManagedDataAcccess. for example `ExecuteNonQuery()`

Comment: Can you please explain how can I, for example, create new data file or may be issue ```alter tablespace users begin backup``` to begin hot backup using ```ExecuteNonQuery```

Comment: Did you have a look at the documentation?

Comment: Yes, however could not find significant information guiding in the right direction. If you can point to any such information/resource/docs it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to believe that you had any look into the documentation: [ExecuteNonQuery](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/odpnt/CommandExecuteNonQuery.html#GUID-E1E79471-6037-4490-BDE7-ADE252922C83)

> ExecuteNonQuery is used for either of the following:
>
> - Catalog operations (for example, querying the structure of a database or creating database objects such as tables).

Here is an example (directly copy/paste from the doc)

```
string constr = "User Id=scott;Password=tiger;Data Source=oracle";
OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(constr);
con.Open();

OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("alter tablespace users begin backup", con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

However, I don't think it is a smart design to manage an Oracle Database via web front end. Do you really like to grant `SYSADMIN` privileges to an application server? Such powerful privileges should be limited to DBA's

Just a note, in relational SQL databases `CRUD` operations are typically called `DML`. `CRUD` is more a general term which applies to many technologies.